# Magento grouped products table sorted

Tags: magento, product

On my grouped products page which has about 30 grouped the skus are all over the place and i would like to sort these alphabetically? Searching endlessly to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Open grouped product from admin. Then go to associated products and there is option to set position. Set position according to your choice and product will display in that order.

Other way, if you want sort by name, then you have to overwrite `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Grouped.php` model. Follow this link for help to override and update according to your requirement: http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-grouped-product-type-tutorial/

Comment: i am aware of this method however i've got about 1500 products and this option wont work so well for me.    seems like there should be a way to make every grouped products table sort by sku or title or whatever

Comment: then override product grouped block. will work for all product.